# @api variable name is 'template'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

In my LWC we have a variable name 'template' .

```
@api template
```

Due to which below line is not working.

```
...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')
```

Is there another way to grab all input elements ?

Comment: why can't you renamed the api variable?

Comment: Its a part of managed package. Can we rename a @api variable ?

Comment: well, it can be problematic. then you can use kind of a workaround in your case. create a js file in your component bundle which can have this 'code ...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')' and import it to the component's controller or where you do you want it to see. in this case it would not cause the conflict because from the other file it will not access the api variable

Comment: Is the LWC exposed from the managed package? Is the API property mapped to a target property? These impact whether you can change the property name.

Comment: @PhilW You mean in the LWC descriptor xml file. I don't see any mapped target property for this variable.

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky Tried importing that line of code from an imported function from another js file but no luck.  I guess its not identifying this.template in the new file

Comment: You may find you can rename the property then if the component isn't used in pages or flows in the package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **refs** to access elements in shadow DOM and light DOM. Refs locate DOM elements without a selector and only query elements contained in a specified template. Previously, you could only use `querySelector()` to locate specific DOM elements.

First, add the `lwc:ref` directive to your element and assign it a value. To call that reference, use `this.refs`.

For example, the `<lightning-input>` element has the directive `lwc:ref="myInput"`, which `this.refs` references to access the `<lightning-input>` at runtime.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" lwc:ref="myInput"> 
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export default class extends LightningElement {
      renderedCallback() {
        console.log(this.refs.myInput);
      }
    }
```

Reference Document: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_templaterefs.htm&release=242&type=5